# Issue with axios.post (axiosjs)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, axios

When I make an `axios.post("test.php",{name:"abc"})` request on my local dev server, I can access the data using `$_POST` in `test.php` file but I can't do the same on my live server. I haven't made any changes in the headers in any of the server.

Can anyone think of what could it be? Tried and tested lot of things but no joy.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: No, there are no error messages. It returns 200 OK but I can't access parameters I passed to test.php file

Comment: try accessing the request object to that route that you send the request too, also if you send Ajax post request do you post the additional crsf token ?

Comment: Are you using Laravel? You seem to be posting to a file rather than a route. I doubt this is Laravel. If you were using Laravel you would do instead `$name = $request->name`;

Comment: No, I am not using Laravel. Just trying the axios library out with core php